# Cannot update the Github page after pushing

Tags: github

I am a relatively rookie user of Github. I have a local directory on my machine and pushed its contents to a GitHub repo. However, whenever I access that repo I can see the following message, and it seems that the repo page does not update.

[image]

The repo was pushed correctly using the GitHub token as configured on the website.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You pushed to the `master` branch when you are looking at the `main` branch in the GithHub UI.

Comment: is that a possible way to make the main branch the standard branch that must be showed?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch